# How to make a recyclerview setup with FIrebaseRecyclerAdapter persist with the view model?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, mvvm, firebaseui

I have setup my RecyclerView with FirebaseRecyclerAdapter. I am setting up the FirebaseRecycler through traditional methods like this,
PostsRecyclerAdapter extends the FirebaseRecyclerAdapter

```
    class PostsFragment : Fragment() {
    private lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
    private lateinit var viewManager: RecyclerView.LayoutManager
    private lateinit var mAdapter : PostsRecyclerAdapter

    override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater,
            container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        setHasOptionsMenu(true)

        val view : View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_posts, container, false)



        recyclerView = view.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.posts_recycler)

        viewManager = LinearLayoutManager(context).apply {
            this.reverseLayout = true
            this.stackFromEnd = true
        }

        return view

    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)

    val myTopPostsQuery = FirebaseUtil.getBaseRef().child("posts")
            .orderByChild("timestamp")

    val myTopPostsQuery = FirebaseUtil.getBaseRef().child("posts")
                .orderByChild("timestamp")
        val options : FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Post> = 
        FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Post>()
            .setQuery(myTopPostsQuery, Post::class.java)
            .build()
        mAdapter = PostsRecyclerAdapter(options)

        recyclerView.layoutManager = viewManager
        recyclerView.adapter = mAdapter

    }


    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        mAdapter.startListening();
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
        mAdapter.stopListening()
    }
}
```

How can add ViewModel to this thing? I want to use MVVM in my app.

---

Comment: Wondering the same here. Any progress @curiousgeek?